# pandas read frame and subsequent type manipulation issue

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Hello I am a rookie with pandas and have the particular behavior that I want to know the reason for

```
sqlnew = 'select FUND_NO,START_DATE,END_DATE,CASH,BOND,SMALL_CAP,LARGE_CAP,INTERNATIONAL from ODSACT.ACT_SRC_FUND_MAPPING;'
ActualFundMapping = psql.read_frame(sqlnew,cnxn)
```

'Everyworks fine until the above'

```
ActualFundMapping.dtypes::

FUND_NO           object
START_DATE        object
END_DATE          object
CASH             float64
BOND             float64
SMALL_CAP        float64
LARGE_CAP        float64
INTERNATIONAL    float64
```

'So since I want to stuff like datetime.datetime(2013,1,1) in ActualFundMapping['START_DATE'] I try changing the dtype as below

```
ActualFundMapping['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(str(ActualFundMapping['START_DATE']))
ActualFundMapping['END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(str(ActualFundMapping['END_DATE']))
ActualFundMapping['FUND_NO'] = ActualFundMapping['FUND_NO'].astype(np.int64)
```

'But existence tests come back false

```
datetime.datetime(2012,1,1) in ActualFundMapping['START_DATE']
False
```

"That entry exists in the sql table and I have verified it

where as

```
str(datetime.datetime(2012,1,1)) in str(ActualFundMapping['START_DATE'])
True
```

'the same issue repeats with the following

```
np.int64(1000) in ActualFundMapping['FUND_NO']
False
```

I guess I am not understanding the representation that pandas use internally. Any help is greatly appreciated.

*******UPDATE*******

upon further advice I made the START_DATE column of the sql table as the index column of the dataframe.

`ActualFundMapping = psql.read_frame(sqlnew,cnxn,'START_DATE')`

`ActualFundMapping.index`

[2012-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2012-01-01 00:00:00]
Length: 895, Freq: None, Timezone: None

```
datetime.datetime(2012,1,1) in ActualFundMapping
False
```

`datetime.datetime(2012,1,1) in ActualFundMapping.index`

False

`np.datetime64(datetime.datetime(2012,1,1)) in ActualFundMapping.index`

False

Comment: Thanks Ed for the edit. I was in the process of changing it myself. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `str(ActualFundMapping['START_DATE'])`, you are converting the entire column to a single string.  I believe pandas stores strings as dtype `object` (to avoid the truncation issues that arise when using numpy string dtypes).  Try just using `pd.to_datetime(ActualFundMapping['START_DATE'])`.  If it raises an error, then there may be mixed-type data in the column, and you will have to do some more detective work to figure out which individual values are causing problems.

As unutbu suggests, you also need to be sure to check for membership in the Series values, not the index.

Comment: as suggested I removed the string wrapper and performed the membership tests as above and again get a false

Comment: @user751279: Then you're going to need to provide a self-contained, runnable example with sample data illustrating the problem.

Comment: Got about my business alright now. Needed some playing around but I get general gist of things

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
value in df['START_DATE']
```

Pandas calls `df['START_DATE'].__contains__(value)` which, as you can see [from the source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L686), tests if `value` is in the info axis (i.e. the Series index).
That's not what we want.

There are many ways around this. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'START_DATE':[DT.datetime(2013,1,1)] 
                   , 'FUND_NO': np.array([1000], dtype=np.int64)})
```

Create a DatetimeIndex and call `DatetimeIndex.__contains__`:

```
In [94]: DT.datetime(2013,1,1) in pd.DatetimeIndex(df['START_DATE'])
Out[94]: True
```

Create a boolean mask, then call `any()`:

```
In [102]: (df['START_DATE'] == DT.date(2013,1,1)).any()
Out[102]: True
```

Drop down to NumPy datetime64s and use `ndarray.__contains__`:

```
In [126]: np.array(DT.datetime(2013,1,1), dtype='<M8[ns]') in df['START_DATE'].values
Out[126]: True
```

Similarly, `1000 in df['FUND_NO']` does not work as desired because again this is testing if `1000` is in the index of `df['FUND_NO']`. Workarounds include:

```
In [96]: (df['FUND_NO'] == 1000).any()
Out[96]: True
```

or

```
In [127]: 1000 in df['FUND_NO'].values
Out[127]: True
```